# Accepting integer user input of unknown size within a single line into an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, user-input

I am tasked to create an integer array with user input of unknown size up to a maximum of 20 and output it in C programming language..
The sample input is

```
   "10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1"
```

or

```
    "20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1"
```

How will I be able to scan the single input into an array, ignoring the ','? Will defining the maximum array size limit me?

```
int array[20];
printf("Enter sample input: ");
scanf("%d",&array);
for (int i=0;i<sizeof array;i++)
{
     print(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Read the entire line, then split it up and convert from strings to ints.

Comment: How would you scan a *single* value into a *single* `int` target? A loop and some form of *that* will be involved. The only difficulty would then be skipping the commas. Regardless, a search on this site of [`[c] read list of integers`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+read+list+of+integers) should certainly be educational.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store all the values in an array directly or read each value using a loop because in that case you would need to know first how many values are read.

What you can do is read the input as a string and then split it to get each value.

```
const int MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 500;
int main() {
  char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
  fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, stdin);

  // The size of your array could be the number of commas + 1
  int size = 0;
  // Iterate your input and count the commas...

  int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  
  int currentIndex = 0;
  // Split the input and store each number:
  char *token = strtok(input, ",");
  while(token != NULL) {
    int num = atoi(token);
    numbers[currentIndex] = num;
    currentIndex++;
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
  }

  // Don't forget to free the dynamic array at the end
  free(numbers);
}
```

Notice that the input string is modified every time you call the `strtok` function.

Some references to the functions used above:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/